# how to start a countdown timer on activity start without any action performed?

Tags: android, timer

I have written a program for a countdown timer but the countdown starts only on button click , but i want it to start without the button click , can anyone suggest me how to do it without the button click ?

Here is the code for countdown timer

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
boolean timehasstarted = false;
Button btnStart;
TextView timer;
long startTime = 30 * 1000;
long interval = 1 * 1000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
    timer.setText(timer.getText() + String.valueOf(startTime / 1000));
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!timehasstarted) {
                countDownTimer.start();
                timehasstarted = true;
                timer.setText("Stop");
            } else {
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                timehasstarted = false;
                timer.setText("Restart");
            }
        }
    });
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(startTime, interval) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timer.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            timer.setText("Time's Up!");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Why  you cant start your timer in onCreate()

Comment: how are you suggesting me to do it sir ??

Answer (score 1):

Move your timer code to `onCreate()` method of the Activity instead of the `onClick()` method

This will start the timer on activity start.

And also you can use  `timer.cancel()` to cancel the timer when the activity is stopped or not currently active

Answer (score 0):

if you want to turn on the countdown after a particular time say after 2 sec then you can use TimerTask for this for exmaple :

```
             Timer t = new Timer();
            t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {



                }
            }, 2000);
```